# Fetch inverse-relationship, rather than NSSet in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa, core-data

I'm new to Core Data.

In the Data Model I have the entities:

- `Song`
- `Playlist`

This is the relationship:

- Every `Song` belongs to no, one or multiple `Playlist`'s

The I've added the relationship to the model like this. 
I also made the inverse **To-Many Relationship**.

Now my question.

The `Playlist`'s now have a `NSSet` with all the `Song`s.
So I can access them via `playlist.songs`.

I can fetch any specific `Song` using a `NSPredicate`:

```
- (NSArray *)fetchWithEntity:(NSString *)entity
                   predicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
             sortDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors
                       error:(NSError **)error {

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                              entityForName:entity
                                              inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSArray *fetchResult = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:error];
    return fetchResult;
}
```

However, I'd like to be possible to filter the `Song`s of a specific playlist too, rather than having to filter the `NSSet` with an `NSPredicate`, because it's simply faster.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The get songs of a specific playlist, just add `"playlist = %@"` to the predicate used for fetching `Song` objects, e.g.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"playlist = %@ AND title CONTAINS[cd] %@",
             thePlaylist, songTitle]
```

Or, if the playlist is given by a title:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"playlist.title = %@ AND title CONTAINS[cd] %@",
             playlistTitle, songTitle]
```

**EDIT** If there is a many-to-many relationship between Songs and Playlist, you can define `playlists` as to-many relationship from *Song* to *Playlist*, as inverse relationship to `songs`. Then the following predicate should work:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY playlist = %@ AND title CONTAINS[cd] %@",
             thePlaylist, songTitle]
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, because a song doesn't have a `playlist` property. The song can be added to multiple playlists...

Comment: @NSAddict: OK sorry, did not read correctly. So it is a many-to-many relationship between Song and Playlist?

Comment: Yes, it is. So the playlists have a property `songs`, but the song doesn't know in what playlists it is.

Comment: @NSAddict: But you can define the inverse relationship `playlists`, then each song known which playlist it belongs to.

Comment: Ok, that would give me an `NSSet` of `playlists`, wouldn't it? How could I filter this with a predicate?